# Display message box in windows by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows

I don't want you to give me the code, but just to tell me if the concept is possible.
Calling a windows API by JavaScript and display a message box, like "hello world".
Is that even possible? Which windows API should you call?

Comment: you can't call a windows api from a web browser. you can create dialogs with `alert`

Comment: @DanielA.White JavaScript does not require browser anymore. NodeJS allows JS to be ran outside of the browser.

Comment: /*Is this what you were looking for?*/ const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

const messag = "Hello world";

spawnSync("powershell.exe", [`
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework;
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('${messag}');
`]);

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if by 'window' you mean browser window or OS window. For browser window, you could use [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) or `window`'s [open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). If you want to open an OS window, [ElectronJS](https://electronjs.org) is just the perfect tool.

Comment: Ok, so ElectronJS seem to do the job. However it seems that it requires npm and node. So if I build a hello world pop-up app, if I will run on a different computer, will it work if node is not installed?

Comment: `npm` is a must to develop, build, and package the app. However, your app's installation as `.exe`, `.dmg`, `.app`, or otherwise doesn't require `npm`; the built and packaged executable would include it.

Comment: I mean OS window.